# How To Search For Files NOT Checked Out In TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, version-control, source-control-explorer

I have a large TFS 2012 database with several thousand files. I would like to search the repository for a certain file extension to see which files have NOT been checked out by any user (so I can then check them out to prevent tampering). All I have seen is articles/questions asking how to see what IS checked out. I would like to do the opposite. Any ideas?

Comment: Why you need to check out the files which not checked out to prevent tampering?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to prevent tampering of files is Blocking by **Permissions**, For a signal file, on the file (requires administrative privileges):

1. Right click the file > click Properties > Security
2. Add your user and mark Deny on the Check Out permission

For your situation, you may need to use [tf permission](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/permission-command) command to deny a certain file extension such as `*.CS` to be checked out for edit.

Comment: I haven't thought of this approach. Good idea. Thank you.